# Repositioning absolute element to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Hi, I'm working on a simple app, that if click it will animate and move to right. My problem is its moving to the opposite direction. I tried using `css()`, it worked but there's no animation. How can I do that? or is there another way to make it work.

Thanks, Hope you understand me.

```js
$('.circle').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      right: 200,
      top: 200,
      margin: 0
    },1000);
});
```

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use margin to center it, use `calc` like in example below:

```js
$('.circle').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    right: 50,
    top: 25
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  right: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove `margin: 0` from the jQuery and change the `right` property to `left`. (See [this](https://codepen.io/happikitsune/pen/mGrPQw) pen for a working example.)

The jQuery would then look like this:

```
$('.circle').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: 200,
      top: 200
    }, 1000);
});
```